# PHP | parse error T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: php

Hi i'm learning some basic php, and i'm having some a parse error. It says that the error is located on line 8(if($book=>$find)). What is wrong with line 8?

```
function getPrice($find)
{
    $books = array ("java"=>299,"c"=>348,"php"=>267);

    foreach ($books as $book=>$price)
    {
        if($book=>$find)
        {
            return $price;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

thank you in advance :D

Comment: change this line `if($book=>$find)` to `if($book==$find)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `==` or `===` to compare change here

```
if($book == $find)
```

Also no need to write `break` after `return` here

```
return $price;
        break;
```

By the way you can also write your code like this

```
<?php

function getPrice($find)
{
   $books = array ("java"=>299,"c"=>348,"php"=>267);
   if(isset($books[$find])){
     return $books[$find];
   }
   return false;
}
echo getPrice("java");
?>
```

Check here : https://eval.in/592069

Comment: ohhh lol what a rookie mistake. thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax:

```
 if($book=>$find)
```

is incorrect.

From what I see, it seems like you want to find a book which matches $find.

Try this instead:

```
if ($book==$find)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I thought that I typed "==" LMAO. thank you